TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str; Failure when trying to download more than one file at once from a website
Relatively new to Python and, by definition, the Discord API. The second part doesn't really matter. I am trying to grab any number (1-10) of posts from a website using their API and am unable to and only one image can be downloaded into the cache folder. I've searched quite a bit but didn't really understand any of the solutions well enough to actually implement a fix.
    @group.command(name="search", description="Search for posts.")
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, search: str, amount: app_commands.Range[int, 1, 10]):        
        async def main():
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(f'-------------------------------') as response:
                    ImageUrl = []
                    Post = []

                    data = await response.json()
                    for post in data['posts']:
                        ImageUrl.append(post['file']['url'])
                        #Post.append(f"{post['id']}.{post['file']['ext']}")
                    
                    print(ImageUrl)
                    print(Post)
                    
                    for url in ImageUrl:
                        async with session.get(url) as response2:
                            print(await response2.read())
                            imgdata = await response2.read()
                            with open(f"./cogs/cache/{post['id']}.{post['file']['ext']}", "wb+") as f:
                                f.write(imgdata)

                                                                                                                
        asyncio.run(main())

Tried multiple forms of this same concept, each of which have not been successful. Essentially, I'm needing to first: grab the image from each post, then grab the image from each image URL, and place the images into a temporary folder.
The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 827, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(self.binding, interaction, **params)  # type: ignore   
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 376, in _build_url    url = URL(str_or_url)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\yarl\_url.py", line 179, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Constructor parameter should be str")TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 376, in _build_url    url = URL(str_or_url)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\yarl\_url.py", line 179, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Constructor parameter should be str")TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Mae\Desktop\Programming Funnies\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'search' raised an exception: TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str


If you trust the URL, then you may need to treat it as pre-encoded. See (particularly the note at the end of  the section): https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls
